# setState() called after dispose(): _StatefulBuilderState#09642(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm showing content with bottomsheet, i'm updating folder size after calculating it, using statefulbuilder's setState, **i used mounted condition** also, then also it showing **setState after called dispose**, Help me to solve this.

```
FileStat fileStat = selectedFilesAndFolders.last.statSync();
  String size = '0 KB';
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
      )),
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, newSetState) {
          getFolderSize(selectedFilesAndFolders.last.path).then((value) {
            if (!mounted) return;

            newSetState(() {
              size = value;
            });
          });

          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Info',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text('Name: '))),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(path
                            .basename(selectedFilesAndFolders.last.path)))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text('Size: '))),
                    Expanded(child: Text(size)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: Text('Last Modified Date: '))),
                    Expanded(child: Text(fileStat.modified.toString()))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```dart
if (!mounted){
    setState(() {
        size = value;
    }),
};
```

Comment: if i use above condition, then setState will not work when bottomsheet is open. I tried your code. now error not came, but setState not called to update the size.

Comment: in your code, you called `newSetState` however it seems you need to call `setState`, I've updated my answer to reflect this